# Are there any strong reasons to use DI for sub-classes that are known to be tightly coupled to their parent containers?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, php, refactoring, coupling

I have Product classes for Products A through Z.  And each Product class has its own set of product-specific subclasses, which I'd say are tightly coupled to them, like so:

```php
//specific product class inherits from generic product
class ProductA extends Product
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //product-specific subclasses that are tightly coupled to the product
        //note that they are not DI-ed, although they *could be*
        $this->weight = new WeightA();
        $this->spec = new SpecA();
    }
}

class Product
{
    public $weight;
    public $spec;

    function __construct()
    {
        //these are generic versions in case someone calls a generic product class   
        $this->weight = new Weight();
        $this->spec = new Spec();
    }    
}

//example instantiation
$p = new ProductA();
$p->weight->a_specific = 4;
```

**Question:**

I spent a bit of time reflecting on whether I wanted to pass my `Weight` and `Spec` subclasses using Dependency-Injection techniques, like so (adjusting my classes respectively):

```
$p = new ProductA(new WeightA(), new SpecA());
```

But so far I have found no good reason to do so.  In fact, doing so may increase the chance of error where I can by accident do something like this:

```
$p = new ProductA(new WeightB(), new SpecC()); //note the disparate classes
```

Question:

- Are there any good reason to DI tightly-coupled subclasses into generic class containers anyway?
- is there a common name for this issue (pattern) that I am dealing with?
- are there other (better) patterns available to use in my instance?

**Background:**

I am refactoring a large ball-of-mud application and it is getting some shape, but one of the patterns I have identified is that there are product-specific classes that contain a lot of product-specific sub-classes, such as in the above example.

**Possible Middle-Ground:**

Note:  alternatively if I really want to DI, I can use DI inside product-specific subclasses, injecting subclasses into the parent container (opposed to injecting it from the outside into the product-specific classes themselves like I have done above), like so:

```
class ProductA extends Product
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(new WeightA(), new SpecA());
    }
}

class Product
{
    function __construct($weight, $spec)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;
        $this->spec = $spec;
    }    
}
```

I wonder if that will be a better option overall.  One problem with it is that `ProductA()` has no parameters but `Product($weight, $spec)` will have two parameters, which is an inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

Why is the tight coupling an issue? If I create a class containing two integer fields or properties, it is tightly coupled to the implementation of integers. Is this a problem? Only if you need to change the integer to a different type, selecting that type at run time.

The premise behind the question (tight coupling is a problem) seems flawed. We can always add more DI and more abstractions. But does it add anything from the user's viewpoint? Does it improve readability and reduce complexity? If you are adding things that are not needed, the answer is always no.

Comment: Good answer.  I like to start by writing things fairly concrete, and abstract them as requirements demand it.  Abstraction for abstraction's sake is YAGNI.